# Capitalize a cyrillic strings with JavaScript

Tags: angularjs, regex, angular-filters, capitalize

I'm making an AngularJS filter which capitalizes each word's first letter.
It works well with a-zA-Z letters, but in my case I use also cyrillic characters and I would like to make it work.

```
var strLatin = "this is some string";
var strCyrillic = "това е някакъв низ";

var newLatinStr = strLatin.replace(/\b[\wа-яА-Я]/g, function(l){ 
    return l.toUpperCase();
});

var newCyrillicStr = strCyrillic.replace(/\b[\wа-яА-Я]/g, function(l){ 
    return l.toUpperCase();
});
```

Here I got some CodePen example: http://codepen.io/brankoleone/pen/GNxjRM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom word boundary that you may build using groupings:

```js
var strLatin = "this is some string";
var strCyrillic = "това е някакъв низ";
var block = "\\w\\u0400-\\u04FF";
var rx = new RegExp("([^" + block + "]|^)([" + block + "])", "g");

var newLatinStr = strLatin.replace(rx, function($0, $1, $2){ 
    return $1+$2.toUpperCase();
});
console.log(newLatinStr);
var newCyrillicStr = strCyrillic.replace(rx, function($0, $1, $2){ 
    return $1+$2.toUpperCase();
});
console.log(newCyrillicStr);
```

**Details**:

- The `block` contains all ASCII letters, digits and underscore and all basic Cyrillic chars from the [basic Cyrillic range](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0400-04FF) (if you need more, see [Cyrillic script in Unicode ranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode) Wiki article and update the regex accordingly), perhaps, you just want to match Russian with `А-ЯЁёа-я`, then use `var block = "\\wА-ЯЁёа-я`
- The final regex matches and captures into Group 1 any char other than the one defined in the block or start of string, and then matches and captures into Group 2 any char defined in the block.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Lodash, you can use [`_.startCase`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#startCase) instead of your own implementation (they do it by splitting the string into words, capitalizing the 1st character of each word and then joining them back together)

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
function capitalizer(string) {
  return string.split(/\s/).map(function(item){
    return (item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1))
  }).join(' ')
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/grishkovelli/8sspafyk/)

Comment: No, this will captialize the letters at any positions. A custom word boundary is required here.

Comment: I agree, this example returns `"ТОВА Е НЯКАКЪВ НИЗ"`, but I rather need `"Това Е Някакъв Низ"`

Comment: Sorry guys, 1min)